# question regarding group theory proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Can someone please explain the sentence in red?, how does it follow?

[image]

Comment: If $\;G\;$ is cyclic and $\;|G|=n\;$ ,then for *any* divisor $\;d\;$ of $\;n\;$ there exists one **unique subgroup** of $\;G\;$ of order $\;d\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc Thanks, but isn't your statement a part of the theorem, something we are trying to prove?

Comment: No. What you undermarked in red is *not* the theorem but something that can be deduced from it! The theorem can be proved independently from your question, of course.

Comment: @Timbuc What I meant is, your sentence "If G is cyclic and |G|=n ,then for any divisor d of n there exists one unique subgroup of G of order d . ", seems the same as "Also $<a^s>=<a^t>$, if and only if gcd(s,n)=gcd(t,n)", which is the last sentence in the theorem. And this is what they are trying to prove where I marked in red?

Comment: As far as I can see, what you marked in red is that there's a unique subgroup of $\;\Bbb Z_n\;$ for each divisor of $\;n\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc The point is that the sentence you use (unique subgroup), is a part of the theorem, just written another way. And when proving a theorem, we can not use the theorem itself, then it is a circle proof.

Comment: Oh, my: do you *really* think I don't know that?! Because if you do then you know better than I do and you don't need my help. What I'm using here is a theorem which is **not** the one they're trying to prove. Whether they already proved it or not is another matter.

Comment: The proof given in the book you quote could have used another step: if $m$ has order $d in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$, then $dm \equiv 0$ (mod $n$), (we are writing the group additively), so that $m$ is a multiple of $\frac{n}{d}.$ Hence $\langle \frac{n}{d} \rangle$ contains all the elements of order $d$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}.$ This is why it is the only cyclic subgroup of order $d$.